# Генерация простого случайного числа в пределах UInt32

Tags: c#

Можно генерировать случайное число и проверить его на простое и сформировать следующее если оно не простое, но это долгий процесс, есть ли быстрые алгоритмы генерирования случайного простого числа на C#?

Comment: [Решето Эратосфена](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve).

Comment: Оформите как ответ пожалуйста. Спасибо.

Comment: Как вариант, собрать в некоем хранилище известные простые числа из необходимого интервала и случайным образом выбирать из них.

Comment: @Aleksandr Zharinov боюсь их будет слишком много

Comment: Я бы еще в цикле брал инкремент + 2. Все таки простые числа - нечетные

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для поиска всех простых чисел в отрезке от 1 до n вы можете использовать решето Эратосфена. Его описание и реализация приведены [здесь](http://e-maxx.ru/algo/eratosthenes_sieve).

```
int n;
vector<char> prime (n+1, true);
prime[0] = prime[1] = false;
for (int i=2; i<=n; ++i)
    if (prime[i])
        if (i * 1ll * i <= n)
            for (int j=i*i; j<=n; j+=i)
                prime[j] = false;
```

Моя реализация на C# ([ideone](http://ideone.com/s1UWB2)):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static List<int> get_primes (int n) {

        bool[] is_prime = new bool[n+1];
        for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i) 
            is_prime[i] = true;

        List<int> primes = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 2; i <= n; ++i)
            if (is_prime[i]) {
                primes.Add(i);
                if (i * i <= n)
                    for (int j=i*i; j<=n; j+=i)
                        is_prime[j] = false;
            }

        return primes;
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        List<int> primes = get_primes(20);
        Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", primes));
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы пробовали этот код собрать и запустить? Само собой, после исправления явной ошибки в первой же строке...

Comment: @PinkTux, этот код для демонстрации, а не для запуска. В данном случае идет указание на то, что переменная `n` целая.

Comment: Демонстрации чего - что вектор на 4 с лишним миллиарда значений создать не получится? Тогда да :)

Comment: @PinkTux, если вас что-то не устраивает, то вы можете исправить вопрос, нажав кнопку "править" под ответом.

Comment: @SergeyPestov не может, потому что он не Дмитрий Чистик

Comment: @PavelMayorov, если я не ошибаюсь, то так если не исправляется ответ, то правка отправляется на рассмотрение.

Comment: Я бы немного упростил это ваше решето. Там в памяти изначально хранится весь ряд целых чисел от 1 до n, а я бы начал с пустого листа. То есть берем проверяемое число и пытаемся разделить его на все элементы листа по очереди. Если нет делителя, добавляем число в этот лист. Ну и так далее. Единицу можно пропустить сразу

Comment: Учитывая что операция деления во много раз дороже умножения это не лучшее решение.

Answer (score 1):

Тут может быть два основных подхода:

1. Сгенерировать список простых чисел в нужном диапазоне заранее и делать случайные выборки из него.
2. генерировать случайное нечётное число и проверять его на простоту.

Первый способ - самый быстрый (время на генерацию списка не учитываем, это происходит один раз, а может и не происходит вообще - готовых списков простых есть где взять), но требует какого-то хранилища. Если речь идёт о диапазоне до UInt32, я бы таскал за собой обычный бинарный файл, забитый 4-хбайтовыми значениями.

Способов генерации списка простых в заданном диапазоне - навалом (если лень искать готовые списки). Например (в отличие от приведённого решета Эратосфена хранит только сгенерированные простые, а не все числа из диапазона вообще):

```
std::vector<unsigned int> primes;
primes.push_back(2);
for (unsigned int i = 3; i < UINT_MAX; i += 2) {
    if ((i > 10) && (i % 10 == 5)) {
        continue;
    }
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < primes.size(); j++) {
        if (j * j - 1 > i) {
            primes.push_back(i);
            break;
        }
        if (i % j == 0) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            primes.push_back(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Второй - медленней, но не требует никаких накладных расходов. В данном диапазоне я не вижу никаких причин не использовать самый простой и очевидный способ проверки на простоту:

```
int is_prime(unsigned long n) {
    for(unsigned long i = 3; i * i <= n; ++i)
        if( !(n % i)) return 0;
    return 1;
}
```

Выбор метода - за исполнителем :)